# Form error because of rendering form in modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, materialize

Rails project with materialize framework, what I am trying to do is rendering a form in a modal.
Therefore I have in the application.html.erb:

```
    <!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="signupmodal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <%= render template: "users/new" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The rendered template looks like this:

```
   <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row col s6">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        </div>
      <%= f.submit 'Create my account', class: "btn waves-effect waves-light orange darker-1" %>
    <% end %>
```

But because the rendered template has its own controller, I get the

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

error, because it doesn't know the @user in the application controller. What is the best way to avoid this error?

Comment: Does it really make sense to you to reuse your registration form for login? You're don't need half the fields. It would be far simpler to just create a separate form where you don't need the @user instance.

Comment: Since I don't know your controllers, the only thing I can suggest is change your instance into an object: `<%= form_for(User.new) .... %>`, or assign `<% @user=User.new %>` before rendering the template

Comment: @RubyRacer thanks mate, using <% @user=User.new %> in the application.erb.html did the trick. I guess putting in the controller for the page is the better permament solution, that's why I did this in the end

Comment: @max thanks for the headsup, I was pasting the wrong code, I was trying to render the signup form in the modal, not the loginform